# Server stops suddenly

Tags: java, playframework, netty

I got some jobs executing with the play framework but suddenly get stopped, I used the TRACE and in the end I get this =>

```
20:07:08,999 TRACE ~ connection already null in cleanup : no action
20:07:28,540 TRACE ~ 0 idle channels closed (times: 1st-loop=0, 2nd-loop=0).
20:08:28,554 DEBUG ~ Closing Idle Channel [id: 0x01b140e8, /0.0.0.0:3699 => /190.144.216.75:80]
20:08:28,554 TRACE ~ 1 idle channels closed (times: 1st-loop=0, 2nd-loop=0).
20:08:28,554 DEBUG ~ Channel Closed: [id: 0x01b140e8, /0.0.0.0:3699 :> /190.144.216.75:80] with attachment com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider$DiscardEvent@272393
20:09:28,569 TRACE ~ 0 idle channels closed (times: 1st-loop=0, 2nd-loop=0).
20:10:28,583 TRACE ~ 0 idle channels closed (times: 1st-loop=0, 2nd-loop=0).
20:11:28,597 TRACE ~ 0 idle channels closed (times: 1st-loop=0, 2nd-loop=0).
20:12:28,612 TRACE ~ 0 idle channels closed (times: 1st-loop=0, 2nd-loop=0).
20:13:28,626 TRACE ~ 0 idle channels closed (times: 1st-loop=0, 2nd-loop=0).
20:14:28,640 TRACE ~ 0 idle channels closed (times: 1st-loop=0, 2nd-loop=0).
20:15:28,655 TRACE ~ 0 idle channels closed (times: 1st-loop=0, 2nd-loop=0).
```

In the log I don't get any `Exception`

Comment: What exactly stops? The jobs, the complete play-server or does the server-process die?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because turning the log level to TRACE causes every single piece of information to be logged. Add to it the fact that IO is always slow. This sometimes exposes unusual corner cases in the framework / server because of which you often see unpredictable behaviour.

I suggest changing the level to TRACE only for selected packages.

Comment: I use this line =>
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, Rolling, Console
In the log4j

Comment: Make it `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Rolling, Console` and add another line `log4j.logger.com.foo=TRACE` where `com.foo` is the package to which you want to enable `TRACE` logging. Everything else will be logged in `DEBUG`.

Comment: Here i did it but i get the same =>
08:28:44,588 DEBUG ~ Closing Idle Channel [id: 0x0141e00a, /192.168.208.192:1328 => /190.144.216.75:80]
08:28:44,588 DEBUG ~ Channel Closed: [id: 0x0141e00a, /192.168.208.192:1328 :> /190.144.216.75:80] with attachment com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider$DiscardEvent@1f7ac92
08:28:44,588 DEBUG ~ Closing Idle Channel [id: 0x0176d662, /192.168.208.192:1330 => /190.144.216.75:80]

Comment: And if i run it under windows 7 it works good but when i do it under windows server 2003 R2 happens that i do it with the same virtual machine

Comment: It seems to be the windows server 2003 :S

Comment: Oh is that the case! That's pretty strange then.

Comment: It seems to be and issue with te VM version in the windows 7 i use the jdk-1.6u26 and in the server is jdk-1.6u29 :/